# FCC product landing page problems with icons

Tags: html, css

I´m building freecodecamp product landing page, and I have been stuck for a long time, I can not find the problem.

I´m trying to add icons before text content, just like on the FCC example (before: Premium Materials, Fast shipping, Quality assurance).[HERE](https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/pen/RKRbwL)[1](https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/pen/RKRbwL)

On my own page [HERE](https://codepen.io/robertybner/pen/LYYYMvB)[2](https://codepen.io/robertybner/pen/LYYYMvB), I can not modify my .icons at all, notice the styling I added to .icons doesen not do anything, and I can not figure out, how to put them in front of text, like on FCC example. I have tried many ways, but nothing does anything, like it does not even find the .icon class I have created.

```
#features .icon {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 125px;
        width: 20vw;
        color: darkorange;
      }
```

Please help

Edit: One problem solved. i know how to make the icon in front of the text.

But the main problem still exists. Somehow css does not recognize the above code. I have tried to tag it as imporant, but still nothing.

Edit2: I just moved the not responding code to the bottom of the entire code, and everything magically started working. No idea why, it did not like its previous placement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display: flex` on the containing div (.grid) instead of the icon, like this:

```
.grid {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Hello. thank you for the answer. Now I can get the icons in front of the grid. But the main problem is that the css does not recognize my code on the page I have made.

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not know what the exact problem was. But everything suddenly started to work,I moved the not responding code to the bottom. I guess it did not like the position in the code.

Comment: That's probably because there were other CSS-rules that would overwrite your rules. Moving them down makes your rules more important so they will overwrite the initial rules.